# Quantity increase using plus and minus with jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi i am creating an input number increment using jQuery but no success yet can you please check my code and give me a proper guidance

**[SEE THE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/sGqgD/)**

HTML

```
<div class="sp-quantity">
    <div class="sp-minus fff"> <a class="ddd" href="#">-</a></div>
    <div class="sp-input">
        <input type="text" class="quntity-input" value="1">
    </div>
    <div class="sp-plus fff"> <a class="ddd" href="#">+</a></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".ddd").on("click", function () {

    var $button = $(this);
    var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input .quntity-input").val();

    if ($button.text() == "+") {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
    } else {
        // Don't allow decrementing below zero
        if (oldValue > 0) {
            var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
        } else {
            newVal = 0;
        }
    }

    $button.parent().find("input .quntity-input").val(newVal);

});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The selector for finding your input was incorrect. `.quntity-input` is a child of the `.sp-quantity` which is two levels above the button in the DOM, so you need to use `closest()` with a selector, not `parent`. Try this:

```
$(".ddd").on("click", function () {

    var $button = $(this);
    var oldValue = $button.closest('.sp-quantity').find("input.quntity-input").val();

    if ($button.text() == "+") {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
    } else {
        // Don't allow decrementing below zero
        if (oldValue > 0) {
            var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
        } else {
            newVal = 0;
        }
    }

    $button.closest('.sp-quantity').find("input.quntity-input").val(newVal);

});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sGqgD/3/)

You can also simplify your code:

```js
$(".ddd").on("click", function() {
  var $button = $(this);
  var $input = $button.closest('.sp-quantity').find("input.quntity-input");
  $input.val((i, v) => Math.max(0, +v + 1 * $button.data('multi')));
});
```

```css
.sp-quantity div { display: inline; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sp-quantity">
  <div class="sp-minus fff"><a class="ddd" href="#" data-multi="-1">-</a></div>
  <div class="sp-input">
    <input type="text" class="quntity-input" value="1" />
  </div>
  <div class="sp-plus fff"><a class="ddd" href="#" data-multi="1">+</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh right, i didnt thought about it.. Again thank you for the answer and clarification.

Comment: @VikasGhodke no problem. See my update as to how you can shorten your code using `data` attributes.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, It's also displaying a negative value. Is there any option to stop the value on 0?

Answer (score 3):

Your selector for input should be

```
$button.closest('.sp-quantity').find("input.quntity-input")
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ng7B2/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but no success yet.. see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sGqgD/2/

Comment: works great: you can change the look of design check [this](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/buttons-minus-and-plus-in-input), it also disables the minus sign when lesser than 0.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you mean?

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/MuAj8/)

```
    $('.sp-plus').on('click', function(){
        var oldVal = $('input').val();
        var newVal = (parseInt($('input').val(),10) +1);
      $('input').val(newVal);
    });

    $('.sp-minus').on('click', function(){
        var oldVal = $('input').val();
        if (oldVal > 0)
        {
            var newVal = (parseInt($('input').val(),10) -1);
        }
        else
        {
            newVal = 0;
        }
        var newVal = (parseInt($('input').val(),10) -1);
        $('input').val(newVal);
    });
```

Comment: Nice one, i was trying to solve this since last 30 minutes and thought of asking it on stack overflow and got lots of great answer, +1 for you too.

Comment: Thank you @VikasGhodke :) I just updated this as I originally left out the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="quantity_custom">
   <label class="product-qty" for="Quantity-{{ section.id }}">Quantity</label>
   <button type="button" id="minus"  field='quantity'>
   -
   </button>
   <input type="number" id="Quantity-{{ section.id }}" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" class="qty" pattern="[0-9]*" data-quantity-input>
   <button type="button" id="plus"  field='quantity'>  
   +
   </button>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
    $('#plus').click(function(e){
        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the field name
        fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
        // Get its current value
        var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
        // If is not undefined
        if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
            // Increment
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
        } else {
            // Otherwise put a 0 there
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
        }
    });
    // This button will decrement the value till 0
    $("#minu").click(function(e) {
        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the field name
        fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
        // Get its current value
        var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
        // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
        if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
            // Decrement one
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1);
        } else {
            // Otherwise put a 0 there
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
        }
    });
});
```

DEMO HERE
https://jsfiddle.net/ardianthaqit/1uegt634/3/